# Performing CSV Split effectively keeping limit into consideration

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh, csv

I have to split a large CSV file into multiple small files with a limit of `1000` records in each small file. However, I don't know beforehand how many records will be there in that large CSV file. I have to do this division effectively as shown below,

1. If a large CSV has 1000 records - Don't perform any split
2. If a large CSV has 2000 records - Create 2 files with 1000 records each
3. If a large CSV has 1200 records - Create 2 files of 600 records each and NOT 1 file with 1000 records and 2nd with 200 records.

This division has to be as effective as possible i.e create as few files as possible but try to keep records in each file almost the same without hitting the upper limit of 1000 records in a file.

Wondering how that math equation would look like in a shell script,

```
calculate_number_of_files() {
    max_limit=1000
    total_records=$1

    ... math logic here
}
```

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable with shell please try to write the equation in another programming language and we'll help you convert it into shell.

Comment: You have not written a math equation, just a requirement. Math is: 3475 lines certainly takes 4 files -- 3 x 1000 + 475. Equalise the files with 3475 / 4, which is 868.75. So split to 869 and the last file is one line shorter. There are rounding conditions to deal with.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - I just posted a shell solution. Not optimized in any sense though.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant - Just wrote one.

Answer (score 1):

Stage 1: count the lines (as suggested by Stéphane Chazelas)

```
ROWS=$( wc -l < "$FILE" )
```

Stage 2: find correct number of rows to split. `round(TotalLines/1000)` is the number of files into which the file will be split (2000 will give you 2, and 1200 will too).

```
ROWS=$( echo "scale=0;$ROWS/(($ROWS+999)/1000)" | bc )
```

Stage 3: use `split -l` to cut the file in `$ROWS`-sized chunks:

```
split --lines "$ROWS" "$FILE"
```

Comment: Technically, `wc -l ${FILE}` is more zsh syntax than bash syntax. In bash, you'd need `wc -l "${FILE}"` as bash performs split+glob upon unquoted parameter expansion. `wc -l -- "$FILE"` would be even more correct, but here, you'd want `rows=$(wc -l < "$file")` (or just `rows=$(wc -l < $file)` in zsh as requested by the OP), as otherwise `$rows` would also contain the name of the file.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks! I had not even noticed the zsh tag (my bad).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no CSV field contains newline characters (that the number of lines in the file equals the number of CSV records), and that there's no header row that needs to be replicated to each file, you could do (assuming GNU `split` here):

```
#! /bin/zsh -
ret=0 max=1000
for file do
  if lines=$(wc -l < $file); then
    if (( lines > max )); then
      (( nfiles = lines / max + ! ! (lines % max) ))
      (( lines_per_file = lines / nfiles + ! ! (lines % nfiles) ))
      split --verbose \
            --lines=$lines_per_file \
            --additional-suffix=.csv \
            --numeric-suffixes=1 -- $file $file:r. || ret=$?
    else
      print -ru2 - $file has $lines lines, no splitting.
    fi
  else
    ret=$?
  fi
done
exit $ret
```

Invoked as `that-script foo.csv bar.csv`, and generates `foo.01.csv`, `foo.02.csv`... as necessary. Add `--suffix-length=3` to change the `01`/`02` to `001`/`002` (and allow more than 99 output files).

Those `(( x = y / n + !! (y % n) ))` are like `(( x = ceil(y / n) ))` (integer division, rounded up). `(( x = (y + n - 1) / n ))` as [shown by @LSerni](/a/659898) would also work.

`zsh` does have the `ceil()` function in its `zsh/mathfunc` function, but we'd need to convert numbers from/to integer/float, so in the end it turns out to be a similar amount of effort:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/mathfunc || exit
ret=0 max=1000

for file do
  if lines=$(wc -l < $file); then
    if (( lines > max )); then
      (( nfiles = ceil(lines * 1. / max) ))
      # lines is integer, nfiles is float
      (( lines_per_file = int(ceil(lines / nfiles)) ))
      split --verbose \
            --lines=$lines_per_file \
            --additional-suffix=.csv \
            --numeric-suffixes=1 -- $file $file:r. || ret=$?
    else
      print -ru2 - $file has $lines lines, no splitting.
    fi
  else
    ret=$?
  fi
done
exit $ret
```

Note that it's not a totally optimal splitting in that a `4001` line file would be split into files with 801, 801, 801, 801, 797 lines for instance, whilst one might prefer to have 801, 800, 800, 800, 800 for instance, but that's not a kind of splitting we could do with the `split` command.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution? I think this solution can be made better though.

```
calculate_number_of_files() {
  declare maxLimit=1000
  declare numberOfRecords=3475
  declare filesNeeded=0

  if [[ $numberOfRecords -le $maxLimit ]]; then
    filesNeeded=1
  else 
    filesNeeded=$(echo $(( numberOfRecords / maxLimit )))
    filesNeeded=$(echo $(( filesNeeded + 1 )))
  fi

  echo "Number of files needed --> " $filesNeeded
  lastFile=$(echo $(( filesNeeded - 1 )))

  for ((i=0; i<$filesNeeded; i++)) do
    recordsInEachFile=$(echo $(( numberOfRecords / filesNeeded )))


    if [[ $i == $lastFile ]]; then
      recordsInEachFile=$(echo $(( numberOfRecords - (recordsInEachFile * i) )))
      echo "Number of records in file " $i " --> $recordsInEachFile";
      break
    fi

    echo "Number of records in file " $i " --> $recordsInEachFile";
  done
}
```

This prints,

```
Number of files needed -->  4
Number of records in file  0  --> 868
Number of records in file  1  --> 868
Number of records in file  2  --> 868
Number of records in file  3  --> 871
```

Comment: maxLimit can't exceed